# Reading a file line by line into an indexable structure

Tags: c++, arrays, string, encryption, char

The problem I face is I'm not exactly sure how to create a dynamic char array; as in I can't have the size specified before hand.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void encrypt()
{
    vector<string> myString;
    char alphabet[2][26] = {
        {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'},
        {'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'}
    };
    cout << ">> Enter the string to be encrypted " << endl;
    getline(cin, myString);
    int length = myString.length();
    cout << length;
}
```

I have tried about a billion different snippets of code for this. Can anybody help me? I am looking for an answer that has working code that creates a dynamic array where the users input (which will be many lines of text) is stored in an array where a math formula can be performed on each index of the array.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned this. I have tried about 500 different ways of encrypting the input string, and a lot have worked. there are just drawbacks to each solution I've wrote, such as having to input words one at a time, etc. I scrapped everything I had and gave a blank template to see the general structure of it. There is a decrypt(){} function as well and they are called in my main() function through a switch(input) statement that accepts int inputs.

Comment: If you don't know how to dynamically allocate an array, then probably just can let others copy your work -- it won't do any good for them. Anyway, if you want encryption, use RSA with a key only you know.

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is.  However, instead of `vector<string> myString;` you probably just want `string myString;`

Comment: I don't actually care that people are copying or looking at my code. I just use every opportunity I can to find something to do where I can use code that I write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I hear you asking for is reading an entire file into a string so you can "encrypt" the string.
I copied this code from another web site

```
string str,strTotal;
getline(cin,str);
while ( cin ) {
   strTotal += str;
   getline(cin,str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To load code you can simple use something like this:

```
vector<string> tmp;
string foo;

while(getline(cin,foo) {
    tmp.push_back(foo);
}

for(int i=0; i<tmp.size();i++) {
    for(int j=0;j<tmp[i].size();i++) {
        // here you can operate on strings
        // e.g.
        // tmp[i][j]='x'
    }
}
```

To use that, you have to call your program from command line:

```
myProgram << input.txt >> output.txt
```